# Hardware freeze during disk activity

Tags: linux, hardware, network-attached-storage

I built myself a linux-based NAS. It has several drives of various sizes and ages in an LVM configuration, with 800GB or so of data. The data is served using a simple samba server.

This was working flawlessly, but after physically moving it, it has developed a strange fault: Whenever I do something on the server to cause disk activity, the entire machine freezes *hard*. This has the effect of killing any open network connections to the box, and generally making it useless.

If I leave the machine for a few minutes it seems to come right again, but obviously this isn't really a solution.

There are no error or warning messages in syslog, or the kernel logs. If I power the machine on, and leave it, it runs for several days without locking up. After that time I stopped testing.

It doesn't freeze instantly - obviously it doesn't freeze while booting, and I can normally log in via SSH and start poking around in a few log files for a couple of minutes before it dies.

My question is:

What diagnostic tests can I run to determine the casuse?

Comment: Do you see any console messages?

Comment: No error messages of any kind :(

Comment: Did you figure it out, what caused system hang during disk activity ?

Answer (score 2):

The typicall way to debug these kind of issues is a Debug kernel set to output to the com port. You connect another computer to the port and read the logs. That way you can get a feed of what happens when the system freezes. But it sounds like it's some kind of driver/hardware problem, and those can be very very hard to debug.

Comment: 95% of the time I run into this problem description it ends up being at least one hard drive that's encountering correctable (through multiple retries) errors.  :-(

Comment: I would also suspect the HD or controller, but it's hard to pinpoint it. Replacing the HD and see what happens is obviously an option.

Comment: Well, right now my priority is to get the data off to safety as soon as possible. I might hack up a quick rsync script to retry every 30 minutes on failure, and see how that goes...